# Updating the position of an image

Tags: android, xml, layout

Hi I am fairly new to Drawing with Android.
I was looking for a simplest way to do the following:

1. change the position of an image I have placed at a starting x,y location
2. may layout has background images, etc, I have a frame layout defined with a placeholder in xml.
3. I have found may questions related to moving images on fling, or dragging.

I just need a basic setup, where my code generates a value for x,y and then I just translate the image to
its new location with these x,y values.
i.e. translate.image(x,y);
most items I find get complex dealing with gestures, animations etc.

I have this basic framelayout in my main xml layout:

```
<FrameLayout  
   android:id="@+id/graphics_holder"  
   android:layout_height="170px"  
   android:layout_width="match_parent"

   >
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
FrameLayout myView = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.graphics_holder);  

int toX = 50; // change these
int toY = 100;
LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) myView.getLayoutParams();
lp.leftMargin = toX;
lp.topMargin = toY;
myView.setLayoutParams(lp);
myView.layout(toX, toY, 0, 0); // might be unnecessary
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, so should I remove the FrameLayout in xml, and just use what you have programatically or can I add LayoutParams in xml in place of FrameLayout?

Comment: no you dont need to remove the FrameLayout in the xml. My code is for changing the position of your image without using an animation. Just replace toX and toY with the desired values.

Comment: where does your myView get defined?

Comment: where is the image that I am moving defined, in the view setup?

Comment: I added a bit more code in my answer to be more specific. Your Image is in your graphics_holder, as far as i understand. Or do you want to move your image in the FrameLayout? Then I would recommend a RelativeLayout instead. And in this case you have to use ImageView myView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myimageview)

Comment: can you do same in xml coding? and my question why need to use java coding for design?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't do that in xml only. At least in android. When you want to move something you have to use code behind.